# Changing bar width with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need some help with changing bar width. I am creating a simple horizontal bar graph and need to change the width of the bar depends on the data in percent. jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/kmc3ohab/2/

Thanks in advance

```js
var data = {
    "box1": {
        "bar1": "80%",
        "bar2": "60%",
        "bar3": "40%",
        "bar4": "50%",
        "total": "60%",
    },
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".score-text").html(data.box1.total);
    $(".data").text(data.box1.bar1);
    $(".data").text(data.box1.bar2);
    $(".data").text(data.box1.bar3);
    $(".data").text(data.box1.bar4);
});
```

```css
body {
 background: #efefef;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 text-align: center;
}

h2 {
 font-family: 'Noto Sans', serif;
 color: #b71f38;
 font-weight: 300;
 margin: 0px;
}

h3 {
 font-family: 'Noto Sans', serif;
 color: #444444;
 font-weight: 200;
 margin: 0px;
}

#colLeft {
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
}

#colRight {
 width: 50%;
 float: right;
}

#row {
 background: #e2e2e2;
 width: auto;
 height: 230px;
 margin: 15px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

#insideColLeft {
 width: 30%;
 float: left;
}

#insideColRight {
 width: 69%;
 float: right;
 padding-top: 8px;
 padding-right: 5px;
}

.circle {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 150px;
 position: relative;
 background: #b71f38;
}

.circle:before {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 padding-top: 100%;
}

.circle-inner {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 text-align: center;
}

.score-text {
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 height: 1em;
 line-height: 1em;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.date {
 font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 color: #333333;
}

ul.graph {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
}
 
ul.graph li {
 margin: 10px;
 height: 25px;
 background: #ccc;
 color: #fff;
}
 
ul.graph li.data {
 background: #f4ebb8;
}
```

```html
<div id="row">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <h3>Subtitle</h3>
      <div id="insideColLeft">
        <div class="circle">
          <div class="circle-inner">
            <div class="score-text">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      <div id="insideColRight">
        <ul class="graph">
          <li class="data">bar 1</li>
          <li class="data">bar 2</li>
          <li class="data">bar 3</li>
          <li class="data">bar 4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

What if i have more than 1 data sets ? how do i do a loop to go through every data? Also if i need to load the data from a local csv file. js fiddle updated http://jsfiddle.net/kmc3ohab/6/

Comment: Is your issue is that currently all bar are set to `50%` but they should be like 80,60,40,50 respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/kmc3ohab/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".score-text").html(data.box1.total);
    $(".data").each(function( index, value ) {
        width = eval('data.box1.bar' + (index+1));
        value.innerText = width;
        value.style.width = width;
    });
});
```

Basic answer to your question was setting style.width on each bar element. Expanded on your solution to also:

- doing everything in a loop. Note: Would be better if the bar values were stored in an array so you wouldn't need to use eval().
- properly setting both the text on the bar and the width of the bar in the loop.

**Edit for new question about multiple sections of bars.**

Displaying multiple sections really depends on how you are reading the csv file. Ideally, the data is stored in arrays and looks something like this after it is read:

```
var data =
[
    {
        title: "Title 1",
        subTitle: "SubTitle 1",
        bars :
        [
           { name: "bar1", value: "80%" },
           { name: "bar2", value: "40%" },
           { name: "bar3", value: "50%" },
           { name: "bar4", value: "60%" }
        ],
        total: "60%"
    },
    {
        title: "Title 2",
        subTitle: "SubTitle 2",
        bars :
        [
           { name: "bar1", value: "80%" },
           { name: "bar2", value: "60%" },
           { name: "bar3", value: "40%" },
           { name: "bar4", value: "50%" }
        ],
        total: "80%"
    }
];
```

And you loop over the list of sections like this:

```
data.foreach(function(item) {
    ...
});
```

But the real questions is how are you going to generate the HTML? With document.write()? If the amount of data being read is dynamic and you are creating HTML on the fly, it will be easier to set the properties as you are creating the HTML.

AngularJS would be a better solution here using a ng-repeat. Then you only define the HTML for your sections once. You talk about reading a local csv file. Does that mean this is not a server hosted HTML file? Even so, it is still possible to use Angular with CDNs hosting the files for you.

Comment: What if i have more than 1 data sets ? how do i do a loop to go through every data? Also if i need to load the data from a local csv file. js fiddle updated http://jsfiddle.net/kmc3ohab/6/